# Extending UITextField Class to add view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

I am new to iOS. I want to extend UITextField class for every textfield in my app so that with every UITextField I can have a bottom border and an icon of keyboard. Which may look like below image.

[this is what I am trying it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dHTX.png)

Below is what I have tried but somehow that subview is not coming on screen

```
// InputField.h
@interface InputField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

// InputField.m
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

if (self) {
    self.delegate = self;
    [self prepareTextField];
}

return self;
}

- (void)prepareTextField {

UIView *bottomLine = [[UIView alloc] init];
bottomLine.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                              -self.frame.size.height,
                              self.frame.size.width,
                              self.frame.size.height);
bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self addSubview:bottomLine];

}
```

Comment: You can check material design library for similar effect. And for image on right side you can use rightView property of text field. Let me know if that helps...

Comment: However, if I do same stuff in my viewDidLoad, it works fine. So I am assuming my text field is not available in view hierarchy at the time code hits  `InputField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I created a category instead and `awakeFromNib()` works like charm.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self prepareTextField];
}
```